# In a graph, find longest path with a certain property?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, longest-path

I have a directed graph (more specifically, a control flow graph), and each of the vertices has a set of properties.

I'd like to find (or write) an algorithm that, given a vertex `V` with property `P`, finds the longest path to some vertex `E` such that *all* vertices along `all` possible paths from `V` to `E` contain the property `P`.

### Example 1

Say I had the following graph. (Please excuse the bad ascii drawing.)

```
                    +----+            
           +--------+P   +--------+   
           |        +----+        |   
           |         V1           |   
           |                      |   
           |                      |   
        +--v--+                   |   
   +----+P    ++                  |   
   |    +-----++               +--v--+
   |           |          +----+P    |
   |           |          |    +-----+
+--v--+     +--v--+       |           
|P    +-+ +-+P    |       |           
+-----+ | | +-----+       |           
        | |               |           
        | |               |           
       +v-v--+            |           
  V6   |P    +---------+  |           
       +-----+         |  |           
                       |  |           
                       |  |           
                       |  |           
                       |  |           
                     +-v--v-+         
                V7   |P     |         
                     +---+--+         
                         |            
                         |            
                     +---v--+         
                V8   |!P    |         
                     +------+
```

Starting at `V1`, the longest path where `P` always holds on all possible paths is `V1` -> `V7`. Note that the other paths, say `V1` -> `V6`, are "valid" in that `P` always holds, but `V1` -> `V7` is the longest.

### Example 2

This example is the same as above, except now the `P` doesn't hold in `V3`:

```
                    +----+            
           +--------+P   +--------+   
           |        +----+        |   
           |         V1           |   
           |                      |   
           |                      |   
        +--v--+                   |   
   +----+P    ++                  |   
   |    +-----++               +--v--+
   |           |          +----+!P   |  V3
   |           |          |    +-----+
+--v--+     +--v--+       |           
|P    +-+ +-+P    |       |           
+-----+ | | +-----+       |           
        | |               |           
        | |               |           
       +v-v--+            |           
  V6   |P    +---------+  |           
       +-----+         |  |           
                       |  |           
                       |  |           
                       |  |           
                       |  |           
                     +-v--v-+         
                V7   |P     |         
                     +---+--+         
                         |            
                         |            
                     +---v--+         
                V8   |!P    |         
                     +------+
```

In this case, starting at `V1`, the longest path where `P` always holds in all possible paths is `V1` -> `V6`. The path `V1` -> `V7` is not valid, because there is a path between `V1` and `V7` in which `P` does not hold.

### Further notes about my situation

- The graph could be cyclic.
- The graph will be of a "small to medium" size, with maybe 1000 vertices or less.
- The graph does not necessarily always have one root and one leaf, like my examples above.

### Question

Is there a standard algorithm for computing such paths?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your second example. Do you say there that you want the longest path from vertex `S` to some vertex `E` such that `P` holds on *all* vertices on *all* paths between `S` and `E`? That seems a very strict constraint...

Comment: What about the edge v6 -> v7? Won't that make the path to v7 the longest?

Comment: The problem has no simple solution, as it is easily reduceable from Hamiltonian Path Problem. (Given Hamiltonian Path problem, label all nodes with `p`, and find longest path). Since Hamiltonian path is NP-Complete, so is this problem, and there is no known polynomial solution to it.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele: Yes, what you said is the (admittedly strict) constraint I'm after.

Comment: @doofuslarge Can you clarify:
- Is the start vertex always a fixed detail?
- Does the graph always have one root and one leaf?
- Is the graph always acyclic?

Comment: @user1990169: I assume you are referring to Example 2. In that case, `V7` is not "valid" because there is a path from `V1` to `V7` where `P` does not hold, namely the path containing `V3`.

Comment: @ChristianConvey: Question updated with more detail.

Comment: For every vertex v that does not hold the property P set all its adjacent edges' weights to -infinity. Then use a known algorithm to find the longest path. If your resulting path has length = -infinity it means that there is no path from v to e such that the constraint is satisfied.

Comment: Does the path have to be simple (i.e., doesn't repeat any vertices)?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, the path has to be simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem has no known efficient solution**, as it is easily reduceable from [Hamiltonian Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), which says - given a graph - is there a path that goes through all vertices exactly once?

The reduction is simple - Given Hamiltonian Path problem, label all nodes with `p`, and find longest path. Since Hamiltonian path is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), so is this problem, and there is no known polynomial solution to it.

An alternative is using a [brute-force search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) (simplest form is generate all permutations and chose the best valid one) - but that will become impossible for large graphs. You might also need to consider using a heuristic approach (that finds a "good" solution, but not the optimal), like Genetic Algorithms.

Another possible solution is to reduce the problem to a [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), and use some existing TSP solver. Note that while this problem is also NP-hard, since it is well-studied, there are some pretty efficient solutions for medium size graphs.

Also, if your graph happens to be somehow 'special' (a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) for example), you might utilize some smart techniques to achieve significant speed up to polynomial time, like Dynamic Programming.

Comment: The brute-force search seems like it might work for me in my case, since the graphs I'm dealing with are usually small. How would it work, exactly? Would I just do a breadth-first search on the graph to generate all possible paths from the starting node `V` to all nodes reachable from `V`, and then discard those paths that have a vertex where `P` doesn't hold, and then sort the remaining paths by length?

Comment: @doofuslarge One solution is using a Depth-First-Search, with a dynamic 'visited' set. This set will remember only the vertices visited in the current path, and whenever you backtrack - remove the last vertex from the set.

Comment: I ended up implementing a brute-force algorithm for my problem, which seems to work OK for my smaller graphs.